# How to complete a mips program that makes a sound?

Tags: mips

I am trying to write a MIPS program that makes a beep sound but it doesn't work.

```
.text 
.globl main 
main: 
li $v0,31 
la $t0,song 
lbu $a0,0($t0)
addi $t2,$a0,12 
la $t1,duration 
lbu $a1,0($t1) 
la $t3,volume 
lbu $a3,0($t3) 
move $t4,$a0 
move $t5,$a1 
move $t6,$a3 
jr $ra
syscall 
.data 
song: .byte 69 
duration: .byte 10 
volume: .byte 40
```

Comment: Stricto sensu, you cannot. You need a MIPS computer with some audio hardware (and not all MIPS boards have one)

Comment: Thanks !                                                                                                                 do you mean something like MARS supporting playing MIDI notes ?